# calling convention in c

Tags: c, calling-convention

some one please tell me
how to change the default calling convention in c?

Answer (score 4):

Calling conventions are not specified by the language. They are extensions to your compiler.

That said, commonly you do something like:

```
void __fastcall my_func(void);
```

But this is completely dependent on your compiler and platform.

Answer (score 1):

This largely depends on your compiler, toolchain, and platform. You will need to be more specific on what your environment is, and what you wish to change to.